# Getting undefined variable in Instagram JSON feed via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, instagram

I am trying to get a feed from Instagram using JSON and jQuery to pull specific hashtag images from one particular user - it has been crazy so far and all built from scratch.. now I am stuck - my loop keeps saying Undefined x

This is my code

```
// GET INSTAGRAM FEED 
// Get feed from Instagram based on Hashtag and filter by user
//

var username = 'jdsportsofficial';
var hashtag = 'crlifestyle';
var clientId = '5a79ddf3fa4147ffbea3fc0e38b22014';
var auth_token = ''; // not needed for most
var instaHTML;
var divId = '#instafeed';

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+hashtag+"/media/recent?client_id="+clientId,
    success: function(x) {

    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        // GET THE PICTURE
        // -- options are thumbnail and large - see object for more
        var instaPicture = x.data[i].images.thumbnail.url;
        if (x.data[i].user.username == username) {

            instaHTML += "<div class='CaroselSlideItem'><img src='" + instaPicture + "'/></div>";

        }
        // INSERT THE GALLERY
        jQuery(divId).html(instaHTML);



    }
}
});
```

You can console it via `jQuery('body').html(instaHTML);`

My error is

TypeError: `x.data[i]` is undefined Line 707 in `var instaPicture = x.data[i].images.thumbnail.url;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x.data` has less than 25 results the error could come. Assume `x.data` has only 20 results then when the loop reaches `i=20`, `x.data[i]` will be undefined.

So

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + hashtag + "/media/recent?client_id=" + clientId,
    success: function (x) {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.data.length && i < 25; i++) {
            // GET THE PICTURE
            // -- options are thumbnail and large - see object for more
            var instaPicture = x.data[i].images.thumbnail.url;
            if (x.data[i].user.username == username) {
                instaHTML += "<div class='CaroselSlideItem'><img src='" + instaPicture + "'/></div>";
            }
            // INSERT THE GALLERY
            jQuery(divId).html(instaHTML);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain in a little more detail what you mean by the loop results please?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid assume the array `x.data` has only 20 items then the valid indexes for those items are from 0 to 19... since in your loop you are always iterating from 0 to 24 when the loop reaches 20 you are trying to access the element `x.data[20]` which will be undefined, thus you are getting the error